# What are good resources for getting started with Apache Tomcat 7?

Tags: installation, setup, tomcat

We need to set up an Apache Tomcat 7 installation and get a third party software up and running.  We have never used Apache Tomcat at all, although we are experienced Java developers, for what that's worth.

What are some good resources for getting this up and running and understanding what we're doing?  An installation and setup tutorial would be great.  A walkthrough of the configuration files, what they do, and the common options in each would be tremendous.

Answer (score 0):

All I needed was on the Apache Tomcat site.  The default configuration files are well documented internally.

Answer (score -1):

My advice stay clear of tomcat 7. It is still not largely supported. As an example it does not work with eclipse 3.5. It does not work too well with Axis2 and lots of Java framework. So i guess you are better off with Tomcat 6.

A second reason for using tomcat 6 is that most tutorials are based on tomcat 6. Finally a good place for tutorials will be coreservlets.com

Comment: This may have been true 18 months ago, but in our shop we have lots of Tomcat 7 instances used in production. We haven't encountered any incompatabilities.